# How do I load a java class (not a servlet) when the tomcat server starts

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I need to continuously update and query a mysql database (and I don't think I need a servlet to do this, just a regular java class).  But I don't know how to call that class or run it when the servlet starts.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let that class implement [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). Then you can do your thing in [`contextInitialized()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method.

```
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Webapp startup.
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Webapp shutdown.
    }

}
```

Register it in `web.xml` as follows to get it to run:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.Config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Or if you're already on Servlet 3.0, then just use [`@WebListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) annotation on the class.

Comment: @BalusC, I've seen Tomcat do delayed loading.  Will this run immediately or does this require a request to trigger loading?

Comment: No, this doesn't require a request. You probably had JSP's in mind.

Comment: One question though, what does the @Weblistener annotation do?

Comment: It removes the need to register the listener in `web.xml`. Servlet 3.0 provides a bunch of annotations (`@WebListener`, `@WebFilter`, `@WebServlet`, etc) which makes the `web.xml` (almost) completely obsolete for registering listeners, filters and servlets. You can then even run your webapp without `web.xml` or with a very minimal one.

Comment: Oh wow! That's so awesome. Double thank you!!!

Comment: Annotations are definitely awesome :)