# JDBC Create table

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-mvc, hsqldb

My web application, written in Spring Web-MVC uses JDBC to work with data. I want to make my app to automatically create tables (and schema), when end-user runs it for the first time (but loads created schema, when it runs it again). I'm using HSQLDB as database engine.

Any ideas, how to do it? (I don't want to write inside app special methods to check, does the table exist, and if it is not, to create them. Does any more useful method doing it exist?)

P.S. I'm thinking about using Hibernate instead of simple connection method. Is there any way to solve it using Hibernate?

Answer (score 3):

> I don't want to write inside app special methods to check, is table exist, and if it is not, to create them. Does any more useful method doing it exists?

Just create the DB by the installer of your webapplication. This can also be done webbased.

An alternative is to implement a `ServletContextListener` which checks the DB and creates tables if necessary. The `ServletContextListener` get executed only once during application's startup, so you don't need to check it on every request or so.

Comment: Oh... That's what I need! Could you give me some links or examples of usage ServletContextListener in such situations?

Comment: There's an example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175726/how-do-i-load-a-java-class-not-a-servlet-when-the-tomcat-server-starts/4175742#4175742).

Comment: Yes, I catch it. But I have big troubles of getting beans inside ServletContextListener. How to @Autowire some fields of this class (e.g. some field like: DBInitService dbInitService). It needs, because dataSource is also bean, so it should be autowired to my app. But inside this Listener I can't get any of this classes. Also, I can't make listener to be autowired. How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Spring JDBC has a [standard mechanism for initializing databases](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#d0e24263).

> If you want to initialize a database and you can provide a reference to a DataSource bean, use the initialize-database tag in the spring-jdbc namespace:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">`
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/foo/sql/db-schema.sql"/>
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/foo/sql/db-test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

You can also turn this on or off using system properties:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource"
    enabled="#{systemProperties.INITIALIZE_DATABASE}">
  <jdbc:script location="..."/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

---

About using hibernate: hibernate can also automatically generate a database schema, here's the relevant part of the reference: [Automatic Schema Generation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/toolsetguide.html#toolsetguide-s1)

Comment: If I'd use this property: <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/foo/sql/db-schema.sql"/>, it will recreate schema, if it already exist?

Comment: @Ilnur Two ways to handle that. a) code SQL defensively, e.g. `CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS` b) create a file in a predefined location (e.g. `%HOME%/.yourapp/.schemagen`) check for the existence of this file (e.g. using SpEL: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html )

Answer (score 1):

I have just started to create spring based application. I am using JPA + Hibernate for implementation of database access layer. One good side effect of this way is that it behaviors exactly as you are describing, i.e. the database is created automatically when application starts. It is very convenient. I have not written even one line in SQL for this project and I have database with indexes, foreign and primary keys etc. It's just fantastic and I recommend you to do the same.