# Is it possible to execute a JSP from command line?

Tags: jsp, command-line

I have deployed our War under Tomcat 6.0 into Linux server. In that Linux machine, we don't have permissions to open a browser.

Is it possible to execute a JSP from command line?

Comment: How about any other machine on the network?

Comment: As we dont have http access from our end  , we can do this way only .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use among others [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) (<-- click the link to see the manual):

```
wget http://localhost:8080/context/page.jsp
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I however wonder how that's useful. If you're for example abusing a JSP to do some webapp initialization, then you should instead have done it in a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) (<-- click the link to see the Javadoc).

#### See also:

- [Using special auto start servlet to initialize on startup and share application data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468150/using-init-servlet) (<-- click the link to see an example)
- [How do I load a java class (not a servlet) when the tomcat server starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175726/how-do-i-load-a-java-class-not-a-servlet-when-the-tomcat-server-starts) (<-- link to another example)

Comment: How  ServletContextListener , could help in this case ??

Comment: Click the links in my answer. I edited the answer to point out them for the case you missed them.

Comment: Seems useful , one more query please , assume that the war is placed inside the tomcat ?? Would this ServletContextListener class would be automatically called up when the server is started ??

Comment: That's also answered in the given links. Just register it in `web.xml`.